# Reading parts of a pdf larger than RAM? iText or other library

Tags: java, performance, pdf, memory, itext

I have a pdf with 15gb size and I intented reading it with iText library, when my code read the class PdfReader the wait time is about 5 minutes for get the object PdfReader.  This is slower than I'd like.

1. When this code is executed i have wait about five minutes.

`PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(filename), null);`

2. Next, if I have de PdfReader object I can get any page very fast.

`Document document = new Document();`
`PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream("result.pdf"));`
`document.open();`
`for (int i = 2400000; i <= 2400010; i++) {`
    `copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, i));`
`}`
`document.close();`

Is there any way to read a pdf more efficienty??, i think could read just the xref table and write in the filesystem and next read this bytes and cast in a PdfReader but i don't know if that is possible.

More general, is there a library that can usefully work with PDFs that don't fit in RAM?

Comment: Start by adding 16gb of ram to the machine. You might need more.

Comment: Is your computer paging to disk while the 5min wait is happening?  Or is it just CPU/memory bound?

Comment: What exactly makes your PDF that huge? Does it contain many big images? Or does it contain so very many pages?

Comment: Exactly, every page from pdf have information about a customer, in a grid if i select a row i could get some page associated at this customer, for example.

Comment: my pdf have 2500000 pages, in my app i show a grid with a customer list, when the user selected a row and next click in the button "show information", i should show one or some pages from pdf depending of parameteres of that customer, if the row that i selected have pageStart=15000 and pageEnd=15002 i will show this specific pages inmediatly.

Comment: If I have in memory the PdfReader object get any page of pdf is very fast, my problem is when i want get PdfReader i have wait about five minutes...my question is if there are any way to write this pdfreader object in disk and when i need it i could recovery inmediatly...??

Comment: Have you considered splitting the big PDF into , say, 1000 smaller ones?